# Cluster analysis

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, continuous-data

I am trying to cluster cells (1×1km) over a specific area. Each cell is composed of various habitats defined by a code. (Each habitat consists of 3 parameters, so a habitat code looks like e.g. 1-3-15. There are around 100 different habitats, i.e. max number of combinations of these 3 parameters).

I now try to define clusters according to:

- Number of habitats per cell
- 1st largest habitat covering the cell
- 2nd largest habitat covering the cell and
- Rarest habitat in the cell (I developed a global rarity index for each habitat, and one habitat having the lowest index is chosen per cell).

So the last 3 in the list refer to a specific habitat per cell, and the first is more a quantitative measure of how many are in each cell.

Based on this they'd like to perform a cluster analysis, but I am wondering whether there is a mix up between categorical and quantitative data.

Could anyone please give some advise on what to method to use, e.g. in R? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are there always more than two habitats in a cell? Otherwise the 2nd largest and the rarest will be the same, or the 2nd largest may not even exist...

Answer (score 0):

Standard clustering methods will likely not work for you:
they assume that your data is *distributed* unevenly. If you have a grid of measurements, your data actually is spaced evenly.

So you will need to look at something that can combine these two requirements: the desire to keep contiguous areas together, and analyzing value changes.

You can try to use distance-based clustering algorithms, but you will need to carefully craft a distance function that has the right balance of spatial relationship, and measurement similarity. This is hard, we cannot help you a lot, but it will likely give the best results. Because it uses the *domain knowledge* you have.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation to define an appropriate distance, however the data on which the clustering is to be based do not seem to include the even spacing if I understand the question correctly. They don't mention that they want to keep contiguous areas together (if that were the case, one could include spatial distance in the overall distance.)

Answer (score 0):

You might try using NMDS instead. If you think about it, you are looking at abundance, diversity, and rarity of habitats. NMDS is traditionally used for abundance, diversity, and rarity of *species*, but I have a feeling it might work for your current issue. To do this, you'll need to create a matrix of presence/absence values.

For instance, you might have rows representing the sites, with the column names representing the different habitat types and other site descriptors. For each habitat type you can enter the number of times it appears. By doing this, you will get similar results as a PCA. Even for rare habitats, you will get an arrow pointing in the direction of where the most commonly occur. If you include some other descriptors of the sites, you can investigate even more relationships.